# How to enable Server-Timing in Apache?

Tags: apache

I'd like to make Apache including [Server-timing header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Server-Timing) in response for performance monitoring purposes. Does Apache support the header? I can't find any mention of it in Apache documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, enabling `mod_status` and setting `ExtendedStatus On` in `status.conf`
See docs: [Apache performance tuning](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/misc/perf-tuning.html)
Please note, this maybe a security concern

Comment: Thanks, could you please expand a bit on your suggestion? I enabled mod_status and set ExtendedStatus On but this gives me the server statistics while I need Apache to include request/response timings in its respone for every request

Comment: Which headers is Apache returning now?

Comment: Same headers as before, no server-timing. Here is what I added to httpd.conf: <IfModule mod_status.c>

        <Location /server-status>
                SetHandler server-status

        </Location>

        ExtendedStatus On
</IfModule>

Comment: Sorry.. I  didn't fully understand your question. Then you must use `mod_headers`, there is an explicit example [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html) for timing purposes..

Comment: Thank you, that looks like what I need! By looking at the example though: Header set MyHeader "%D %t" -> MyHeader: D=3775428 t=991424704447256   I wonder if there is a way to get rid of 'D' and 't', just numbers only?

Comment: I don't think it's possible...